# Wildfly logging module exclusion does not work for a large web app

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

I've written a small web app which disables Wildfly 10.1's `slf4j` implementation and uses its own logging libraries (logback). It works fine because `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()` resolves to `ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext` as result.

But then I use the same code for a larger application (with 52 jar files in `WEB-INF/lib/`) `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()` still resolves to a JBoss implementation `org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory`, as by default.

How can I investigate what exactly retains server's logging instead of the one of mine? (And fix the situation of course.)

Maven dependencies used: "slf4j-api" 1.6.1, "logback-classic" and "logback-core" 0.9.28.

File `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, which is known to be located properly in both cases:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.common.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Is this larget application an EAR?

Comment: It's a `war`... I've just found a SOLUTION. The difference is it was dependent on `slf4j-api` as `provided`. Changing it to `compile` solved the task. Althought this is not an answer to my question, I'd like to know how to investigate such problems still.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a old topic but i had a similar problem.
So, i will describe the problem and what i done to solve it.

I'm using spring-boot in my web application and running with jboss wildfly 10.
When i try to integrate sentry and logback on my project, the application reads the file logback.xml but use another logging system.

I realized that wildfly was ignoring logback and using jboss-logging instead.
So, i disabled the jboss logging module and than, my application started using logback and everything worked fine.

But this is how i disabled logging sub-system:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

[The link when i found my anwser:](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-2995)